# Difference between multiple dates in the same column based on category

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have the following problem ..

I have this table:

[image]

I want to create a calculated column that tells me the difference of days between two dates of the same code (**COD**), the difference should be calculated based on the date before the line.

For example:

Using **COD** *B*

**COD |     DATE**  | *days_diff*

B |05/01/2018 |

B |09/01/2018 | *4*

B |12/01/2018 | *3*

In the example image the codes / dates are sorted in sequence, but in reality they are out of order.

I tried to use the following sentence in DAX:

```
 DATEDIFF(Testing[DATE]; FIRSTDATE(FILTER( ALL(Testing[DATE]) ;Testing[DATE] > EARLIER(Testing[DATE])));DAY)
```

**Explaining what I've tried:**

Make the difference between the date on the line and using the *EARLIER* function to get the most recent date out of the current one.

However, I obtained the following result:

[image]

I can not filter **COD**, so that the analysis of 'EARLIER' is performed only in the same 'group', so I understand the PowerBI is considering all the dates.

Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're pretty close in idea, but it needs some tweaking. Try this:

```
Days_diff =
VAR StartDate =
    CALCULATE (
        LASTDATE ( Testing[DATE] ),
        FILTER (
            ALLEXCEPT ( Testing, Testing[COD] ),
            Testing[DATE] < EARLIER ( Testing[DATE] )
        )
    )
RETURN
    DATEDIFF ( StartDate, Testing[DATE], DAY )
```

The variable `StartDate` calculates the last date before the current row date. I use `CALCULATE` to remove all row context except for `COD` since that is what we are grouping on.

Note: The `EARLIER` function is not a date/time function, but rather a reference to an earlier row context (before stepping inside the `FILTER` function). It allows us to jump back a level when we are nesting functions.

Then you just take the `DATEDIFF`.

[image: Days_diff]

Comment: Awesome friend! Really thanks. Thank you for 'EARLIER' explanation.