# How to get earlier value based on a value name in a column

Tags: dax

I would like to get the previous day value depending on an attribute's name hence applying a two-level filter to my calculated column.
I am currently stuck with the following formula giving me a blank column.

```
Column = CALCULATE(
                    MAX(useractivity[Value]),
                    FILTER(
                            useractivity,
                            useractivity[Dates]=EARLIER(useractivity[Dates])-1
                        ),
                    FILTER(
                        an IFS function maybe?
                    ))
```

I would like to have the following output:

```
+------------------+-----------+---------+----------------+
|      Dates       | Attribute |  Value  | Previous_Value |
+------------------+-----------+---------+----------------+
| 31 december 2018 | active    | 100,000 |         80,000 |
| 31 december 2018 | inactive  |  50,000 |         40,000 |
| 29 december 2018 | active    |  80,000 |            ... |
| 29 december 2018 | inactive  |  40,000 |            ... |
+------------------+-----------+---------+----------------+
```

Comment: Backing up one day give Dec 30th.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is similar to my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54044455/difference-between-multiple-dates-in-the-same-column-based-on-category/54045016#54045016). Calculate the previous date and then do a lookup.

```
Previous_Value =
VAR PrevDay =
    CALCULATE (
        LASTDATE ( useractivity[Dates] ),
        ALLEXCEPT ( useractivity, useractivity[Attribute] ),
        useractivity[Dates] < EARLIER ( useractivity[Dates] )
    )
RETURN
    LOOKUPVALUE (
        useractivity[Value],
        useractivity[Dates], PrevDay,
        useractivity[Attribute], useractivity[Attribute]
    )
```

---

**Edit**

As a measure, you need some minor tweaks,

```
Previous_Value = 
VAR PrevDay =
    CALCULATE (
        LASTDATE ( useractivity[Dates] ),
        FILTER(
            ALLEXCEPT ( useractivity, useractivity[Attribute] ),
            useractivity[Dates] < MAX( useractivity[Dates] )
        )
    )
RETURN
    LOOKUPVALUE (
        useractivity[Value],
        useractivity[Dates], PrevDay,
        useractivity[Attribute], MAX(useractivity[Attribute])
    )
```

Comment: how can I use this function within as measure instead? works perfect by the way

Comment: You need to provide an aggregate wherever the calculated column uses row context. Please see my edit.